# Output matrix updating with dots and want I want remove the Dots in array

Tags: python, numpy

```
 import numpy as np
 x = np.ones((5,5))
 print(x)
 x[1:-1,1:-1] = 0
 print(x)
```

I am getting the output as shown below:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), setting it to `int`:

```
print(x.astype(int))
```

Result:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to `1.` When you see a dot sign, you know that that number is float type.

If you don't want floats, you should cast your list to integer:

```
x.astype(int)
```

Other things you should do in python console to understand things a little:

```
print(type(1))
print(type(1.))
print(x.dtype)
print(x.astype(int).dtype)
```